# Can I access a named java bean?

Tags: java, cdi

I'm trying to create a Java EE application with `@Named` component.

```
import javax.inject.Named;

@Named
public class MyNamedBean {
    public int myMethod() { ... }
}
```

But for some reasons, I need to access to this named java bean's methods from another java bean. So how can I do it ? Should I use `@Inject` annotation ?

I don't know what tag should be added. Please edit the question if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the annotation [`@Inject`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/inject/Inject.html) can be used to inject the bean `MyNamedBean` to another bean, then access the method wanted from the injected bean.

Example :

Zoo.java

```
import javax.inject.Inject;

public class Zoo {

    @Inject
    private Dog dog;

    public Zoo() {
    }

    public void talk() {
        dog.talk();
    }
}
```

Dog.java

```
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.inject.Singleton;

@Named
@Singleton // optional
public class Dog {

    public void talk() {
        System.out.println("wowowo~ ฅ^•ﻌ•^ฅ");
    }
}
```

Comment: Good question, I don't know... @PeterRader

Comment: In Spring CDI (i am sure) it must be a Bean (in same scope or same-scoped-proxy) or it must be autowired by the context manually.